# Program that finds the longest word not containing one of the disallowed characters

Tags: c++, performance, strings, file

### Problem definition

Find the longest word that doesn't contain any of the following characters:

```
gkmqvwxz
```

Input comes from a file named [`words.txt`](https://mega.nz/#!V75TWKCT!R41D0y0pgnFXER5jU-Jb7-daAglZN1FNQuiQ-FQgHTw) and contains one word per line. A word is anything that is not a whitespace.

---

### The twist

My C++ implementation posted below is surprisingly slow, taking 1.7 seconds to run, whereas my javascript implementation ([link](https://repl.it/repls/WarlikeRedSphere), will obviously be slower because it's online) takes only 55ms. Is it possible to somehow optimize my C++ implementation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

#include "TimeUtil.h"

int main()
{
    uint64_t begin_time = currentTimeNanoseconds();

    std::string longestAcceptableWord; // Variable to contain the longest word

    std::string currentLine;
    const char badLetters[] = { 'g', 'k', 'm', 'q', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z' };

    std::ifstream in;
    in.open("words.txt");
    while (!in.eof()) // Loop through the entire file (466 544 lines, 4 749 kB).
    {
        getline(in, currentLine);

        if (currentLine.length() <= longestAcceptableWord.length())
        {
            continue;
        }

        // If the word contains one of the bad letters, don't accept it.
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(badLetters); i++)
        {
            if (currentLine.find(badLetters[i]) != std::string::npos)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        // If the word is longer than the current longest word found, 
        // and doesn't have any bad letters, make it the new longest 
        // word found.
        longestAcceptableWord = currentLine;
    }
    in.close();

    std::cout << "[" << (double) ((currentTimeNanoseconds() - begin_time) / 1000) / 1000.0f << "ms] " << longestAcceptableWord << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure it is 55ms and not 550ms? I'm getting 90-100ms on my computer with my C++ implementation.

Comment: Are you sure you enabled all optimizations in your compiler? Because something like a debug mode, or even no optimization could jeopardize performance.

Comment: @Xydez, after testing on the computer of my friend, he got 90ms for javascript version and ~47ms for C++ version with -O3, which I expected. I believe there is some other variable in the benchmark, not only performance of the two implementations.

Comment: Did you try `strpbrk`?

Comment: Your JavaScript solution is broken. It should be `letter of badLetters`, not `letter in badLetters`.

Comment: Folks, don't forget that comments are not the place to make insightful observations about the code. The answer box is right there, use it :).

If you want to banter, [chat] is much more suited to that. I've removed a slew of comments in accordance to the site rules. Thanks!

Comment: How did you compile your C++ code? On my machine the original C++ code is ~ 10x faster than the JS code; both your original implementations, and after fixing the bugs in the JS and C++ code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Using the visual studio 2017 compiler.

Comment: @Xydez That’s insufficient information. Did you enable optimisations? Did you compile in debug or release mode? …

Comment: @KonradRudoph I compiled in debug mode, I don't know how to "enable optimizations".

Comment: Nice to encounter a fellow Tom Scott fan. For those unaware: this program was most likely based on a video Tom released on Monday on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zp4BMR88260, where he gives his own solution for this question.

Comment: I'm assuming the file is lowercased  ahead? All I see is case-sensitive comparisons and the file containing data with uppercase as well...

Comment: @Xydez That’s the issue then, rather than the code: enable release mode (rather than debug mode) and figure out how to enable optimisations (MSDN should have this information).

Comment: @Vogel612 well, you deleted the comment explaining that the OP considers pre-sorting "words.txt" as part of the time to measure for this performance optimization review.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Uhm... switching to release mode turned 2000ms into 80ms. What the heck just happened?

Comment: @Xydez This is fairly normal. In debug mode the code has to maintain a lot of information that prevent efficient optimisation. For example, in debug mode every vector access may check whether the index is valid; in release mode this isn’t done.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sorry for asking, but do you know any post that describes the difference between debug- and release mode?

Comment: @Xydez Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/367884/1968

Answer (score 15):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your program.

### Fix the bug

There is a subtle bug in the original implementation.  It contains these lines:

> ```
> // If the word contains one of the bad letters, don't accept it.
> for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(badLetters); i++) {
>     if (currentLine.find(badLetters[i]) != std::string::npos) {
>         continue;
>     }
> }
> ```

The intent is, of course, to escape the `for` loop and go on if a bad letter is found in a candidate word.  However, what actually happens is that first letter is checked, and the loop continues *no matter if the letter was found or not*.  That's a bug and one reason I don't much like `continue`.  It's too easy to make this kind of error.

### Don't loop on `eof()`

It's almost always incorrect to loop on `eof()` while reading a file.  The reason is that the `eof` indication is only set when an attempt is made to read something from the file when we're already at the end.  So instead of this:

> ```
> while (!in.eof()) {
>     getline(in, currentLine); 
>     // ...
> }
> ```

write this:

```
while (getline(in, currentLine)) { 
    // ...
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) for more details on why using `eof` is usually wrong.

### Initialize variables on declaration

The best practice is to initialize variables as soon as they're created.  In C++, this most often means initializing them in the same line as the declaration.  So instead of this:

> ```
> std::ifstream in;
> in.open("words.txt");
> ```

write this:

```
std::ifstream file2{wordsFile};
```

Note, too, that I use the C++11 uniform initializer syntax (with the `{}`) to make it clear to both the compiler and the reader that this is an initialization and not a function call.  See [Stroustrup's description](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init) for more details on that.

### Allow the user to specify input files

The words file name is currently hardcoded which certainly greatly restricts the usefulness of the program.  Consider using `argc` and `argv` to allow the user to specify file names on the command line.

### Prefer newer structures to plain arrays

Instead of a plain array as with `badLetters`, one could instead use an `std::array` or `std::string`.  If your compiler has C++17 support, `std::string_vew` might be an even better choice.

```
const std::array<char, 8> badLetters = { 'g', 'k', 'm', 'q', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z' };
```

### Use standard algorithms

Instead of searching with a `for` loop for all `badLetters`, we can use [`std::find_first_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of) instead.  The result would look like this:

```
while (getline(in, currentLine)) {
    if (currentLine.length() > longestAcceptableWord.length()
        && (std::find_first_of(currentLine.begin(),
                            currentLine.end(),
                            badLetters.begin(),
                            badLetters.end()) == currentLine.end())
    ) {
        longestAcceptableWord = currentLine;
    }
}
```

Note that I prefer to avoid `continue` and instead rely on the short-circuit evaluation of the `if` clauses to cause the same effect.

### Don't use `std::endl` if you don't really need it

The difference between `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `'\n'` just emits a newline character, while `std::endl` actually flushes the stream.  This can be time-consuming in a program with a lot of I/O and is rarely actually needed.  It's best to *only* use `std::endl` when you have some good reason to flush the stream and it's not very often needed for simple programs such as this one.  Avoiding the habit of using `std::endl` when `'\n'` will do will pay dividends in the future as you write more complex programs with more I/O and where performance needs to be maximized.

Comment: The only time I have had to use `std::endl` was in a utility which needed to write to the console during the building of a Docker image, without it the progress would have been displayed all at once at the end of the utility, which usually ran for a couple of minutes.

Comment: Applying Edward recommendations, here is how it may look like on repl: https://repl.it/@Coeur/LongestWordWithoutDisallowedCharacter

Answer (score 7):

The code is reasonably good. There are some inefficiencies and small bug that doesn't affect the result.

### Bug

`!in.eof()`, `.eof()` is never true until its read. It should be the getline instead.

### Inefficiencies

- reading line by line

It is in general better to just read into string variable, it is clearer and probably more efficient.

- Manually closing the file

Standard file streams close themselves when they get out of scope, which end of `main` in this case.

### Alternative implementation

Now, lets eliminate the main culprit, string validity check:

```
bool is_valid_word(std::string_view word) {
    for (char letter: word) {
        switch (letter) {
            case 'g':
            case 'k':
            case 'm':
            case 'q':
            case 'v':
            case 'w':
            case 'x':
            case 'z':
                return false;
            default:
                ; //silence warnings
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The main change is to use jump table (switch statement) with fallthrough. The other change is to use `std::string_view`, immutable non owning view into string.

The next thing to care about is iteration through the file. My personal preference is to use a pair of iterators:

```
std::ifstream file("words.txt");
auto first = std::istream_iterator<std::string>(file);
auto last = std::istream_iterator<std::string>();
```

And the algorithm itself:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
std::string longest_valid_word(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
    std::string longest_word;
    while (first != last) {
        if (first->size() > longest_word.size() && is_valid_word(*first)) {
            longest_word = *first;
        }
        ++first;
    }

    return longest_word;
}
```

Note that the above algorithm can run on anything that provides a pair of iterators, e.g. `std::vector`, `std::list`, etc.

---

### Full code

No demo for this post, as I don't want to put the weight onto wandbox:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

bool is_valid_word(std::string_view word) {
    for (char letter: word) {
        switch (letter) {
            case 'g':
            case 'k':
            case 'm':
            case 'q':
            case 'v':
            case 'w':
            case 'x':
            case 'z':
                return false;
            default:
                ; //silence warnings
        }
    }

    return true;
}

template <typename InputIterator>
std::string longest_valid_word(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
    std::string longest_word;
    while (first != last) {
        if (first->size() > longest_word.size() && is_valid_word(*first)) {
            longest_word = *first;
        }
        ++first;
    }

    return longest_word;
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("words.txt");

    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto start_time = system_clock::now();
    //std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    auto found_word = longest_valid_word(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(file), {});
    //std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    auto end_time = system_clock::now();

    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end_time - start_time);

    std::cout << "[" << duration.count() << "ms] "
              << found_word << std::endl;
}
```

The atomic thread fences can be uncommented, but they don't really change much in this case. It is probably bottlenecked by performance of my SSD and of `std::ifstream`.

---

### Conclusion

<s>Well, I got around 90-100 milliseconds on my machine. I've got no idea why it runs so slowly, but I've exhausted my sane ideas. The other one would be to do some manual parsing of the file, which is much harder.</s>

Of course it didn't go as I expected :) this is what happens when optimizations are done in a rush. Let me break down why the code above is slower than what Toby and Edward (my speculations from results, of course):

- `std::getline` is faster than using `std::istream_iterator<std::string>`
- using jump table or just using array of bad letters make no difference whatsoever on my timings

### Different version of alternative approach (uses `std::getline`)

```
std::string longest_valid_word(std::ifstream& is) {
    std::string buffer;
    std::string longest_word;
    while (std::getline(is, buffer)) {
        if (buffer.size() > longest_word.size() && is_valid_word(buffer)) {
            longest_word = buffer;
        }
    }

    return longest_word;
}
```

Just paste the function into the code and call it with the file stream, instead of calling the one with iterators.

Comment: @Xydez, feel free to ask questions about the post. Although templates and iterators might be a little bit alien to you, I recommend getting accustomed to them if you're planning to be library developer, as they serve as a great tools for algorithm and data structure abstractions.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what `"TimeUtil.h"` contains, but the standard facilities (in `std::chrono`) are to be preferred for portable code:

```
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    auto begin_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // ...

    auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration
        = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time-begin_time);

    std::cout << "[" << duration.count() << "ms] "
              << longestAcceptableWord << std::endl;
}
```

It's better to separate the actual logic into its own function, separate from the timing and file opening housework.

`badLetters` can have static duration.

We don't need to separately construct and open the input file (and we'd be more flexible if we didn't hard-code that input - why not just read from standard input?).  Also, no need to explicitly close it if we're not using the return value of `close()` - just let the destructor do its job!

`while (!eof())` is an anti-pattern: we should `while (getline())` instead.  The latter actually attempts a read, whereas the former only determines whether the *previous* read hit end of file.

`std::string` has `find_first_of` which tests for all the characters in a set concurrently.  The set does need to be passed as a null-terminated string (or as a `std::string` or `std::string_view`), but that's not hard to arrange.

## Modified code

Applying the advice above, we get:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <chrono>

std::string findLongestLineNotContaining(std::istream& in,
                                         const char *badLetters)
{
    std::string longestAcceptableWord;
    std::string currentLine;
    while (getline(in, currentLine))
    {
        if (currentLine.length() > longestAcceptableWord.length() &&
            currentLine.find_first_of(badLetters) == currentLine.npos)
        {
            // Word is longer than the current longest word found,
            // and doesn't have any bad letters, so make it the new
            // longest word found.
            longestAcceptableWord = currentLine;
        }
    }
    return longestAcceptableWord;
}


int main()
{
    namespace chr = std::chrono;
    auto begin_time = chr::high_resolution_clock::now();

    static const char *badLetters = "gkmqvwxz";
    std::ifstream in("words.txt");
    std::string longestAcceptableWord
        = findLongestLineNotContaining(in, badLetters);

    auto end_time = chr::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = chr::duration_cast<chr::milliseconds>(end_time - begin_time);

    std::cout << "[" << duration.count() << "ms] "
              << longestAcceptableWord << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I like the clean interface for `findLongestLineNotContaining`, but I'd suggest making `badLetters` a better container such as a `std::string_view` or `const std::array`.

Comment: Yes, that's more idiomatic modern C++; `std::string_view` works better, as that's directly accepted by `std::string::find_first_of()`; an array would need conversion (admittedly not hard).

Comment: Actually, there is a standalone `std::find_first_of` that I showed in my answer that accepts any kind of container.  (Frankly, I'd just forgotten about the `string` version until I saw your answer!)

Comment: This is good advice but it doesn’t explain why OP’s C++ code is substantially slower than their JavaScript code. The logic in both implementations is essentially the same (modulo a JS bug pointed out in the comments, and a C++ bug which means that every string, not just a candidate, is copied; both bugs barely affect timing). The C++ code should be a lot faster (and on my machine it’s ~ 10x as fast as the JS code).

Answer (score 2):

The problem's definition doesn't specify that the answer should be in C++.  You can get the answer in less than a second with the following Unix shell pipeline one-liner.

```
$ time grep -v '[gkmqvwxz]' words.txt | awk '{print length($1), $1}' | sort -rn | head -1

31 dichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane

real    0m0.960s
```

Here are the commands explained one-by-one. The commands are connected into a *pipeline* so that the output of each command is filtered by the next one.

```
# Remove lines containing any of the disallowed characters
grep -v '[gkmqvwxz]' words.txt |
# Prefix each word by its length
awk '{print length($1), $1}' |
# Order the output numerically in reverse order
sort -rn |
# Output first line
head -1
```

Alternatively, you might want to write this in a scripting language, which, compared to the C++ implementation, is almost as concise and also executes faster.

**awk**

```
$ time awk '!/[gkmqvwxz]/ && length($1) > max_length {result = $1; max_length = length($1); } END {print result}' words.txt
dichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane

real    0m0.180s
```

**Perl**

```
$ time perl -ne ' if (!/[gkmqvwxz]/ && length($_) > $max_length) {$result = $_; $max_length = length($_); } END {print $result}' words.txt
dichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane

real    0m0.371s
```

Less code means fewer possibilities for bugs and significantly less effort from your part. Nowadays in most cases it's better to optimize for readability and developer effort rather than for CPU efficiency.

Comment: These are *great* solutions but this is a code review site and I’m not sure how much use they’d be to the OP. That said, I actually think highlighting alternative solutions isn’t a bad idea here.

Comment: @DiomidisSpinellis As Konrad said, this isn't of use to me. However I appreciate the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @KonradRudolph It could possibly be useful for others though in this case. I'm normally against "alternative solution"-answers but I consider this as a quite insightful one.